# What's the average cost time for rpc call

Tags: performance, rest, http, tcl, rpc

We have legacy tcl system which talkes to DB directly. Now we want to migrate db logic to middle layer(java). It will be xmlrpc or rest call from tcl to the middle layer. I found the average cost time per each rpc call is 50ms.  Is this normal? Since it is legacy system, there are bunch of db calls per page. The response time per page is slow. The rpc response time per call very matters for us. We have tried to re-design the tcl page to reduce server call. But it will help us a lot if find way to reduce the response time. Appreciate your comment.

Comment: Code? Not much to say without it.

Comment: Simple xmlrpc might be expensive because of all the establishing and tearing down of sockets for the underlying HTTP calls. Have you tried to use Tcl 8.6 yet? I think that comes with a version of the `http` package that supports keep-alive, which should speed things up a lot, at least in this area…